# How to avoid garbage values received in UART communication

Tags: c, uart, error

I am new to the embedded programming. I am doing a UART communication in `PIC32MX795F512L` MCU. I have somehow managed to transmit and receive data but not able to receive complete string.

I am doing something like this:

```
char Rx[5] ;                      //variable to store rx data
int i;
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)  
{
   while(!DataRdyUART1());       //This check if data is ready to be received
   Rx[i] = getcUART1();         //This get one character from UART

 }
 putsUART1(Rx);              //Putting all the Rx data on UART
```

But whats happening is If I type `12345` then I get `123452345&+` its taking the last values. Again if I type `asdfg` then I get `asdfg2345&+`. After the 5th character, its showing some garbage values.

This should not happen. I don't know why its taking up `2345&+`. How can I remove this. Please help. Thanks.!

Comment: This is a classic buffer overflow...

Comment: @Paebbels No, it is a classic "the programmer has not grasped string null termination" beginner bug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string needs to be zero terminated so that the sending function, `putsUART1`, knows when it's reached the end. So make your array one character larger and add a null (zero) at the end.

Something like this:

```
char Rx[6] ;                      //variable to store rx data
int i;
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)  
{
   while(!DataRdyUART1());       //This check if data is ready to be received
   Rx[i] = getcUART1();         //This get one character from UART

 }
Rx[5] = 0;                  // add null terminator
putsUART1(Rx);              //Putting all the Rx data on UART
```